# Timeline - Python - Data Visualization

Tags: python, data-visualization, timeline

I have no code to show at this stage of my question. However, I would like to know if the following project can be realized using Python:

Objective: Timeline showing communications between several individuals
Construction of the timeline:
x-axis: Date and time of the communications
y-axis: Individuals (Subject A, Subject B, etc.)

The y-axis shoudl show a straight line for each individuals from y=0 to y=[the end of the period reviewed]
For each communications recorded (vocal, text messages, etc.), I would like an arrow illustrating the comm' (i.e. Subect A calling Subject B on Feb 1, 2020 at 10:30: an arrow will go from the straight line related to Subject A to the one representing Subject B, and I would like the arrow to mention the type of communication, either a call or text message or whatever).

The link should show you the type of outcome expected:  [Timeline example](http://en.tovek.cz/en/image/imageview/?image=http://en.tovek.cz/navigator-image/600/600/upload/produkty/i2/anb/img_anb2.jpg&text=)

I have unsuccessfully tried to find similar requests.

Thank you for your help and support,

Tom

Comment: doesnt qualify a full answer, but check out this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/timeline.html

maybe you could work off that,

Comment: Some similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009441/making-a-timeline-graph-with-a-dataframe-with-grouped-values-needing-a-for-loop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944182/how-to-create-a-visualization-for-events-along-a-timeline/59948990#59948990)